# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: reactjs, syntax-error

I am just learning react at the moment! I have run into an issue recently where I keep getting

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

The only thing that I have changed once creating the react app, was the text in the App.js file to the following:

```
import React from 'react';

function App(){
    return (
            <button>-</button>
            <span>0</span>
            <button>+</button>
       
    )
}
```

Tried a couple of things that Ive found on older posts, but none of them worked. Any suggestions would be greatly apprecaited!

Answer (score 2):

```
import React from 'react';

function App(){
    return (
        <div>
            <button>-</button>
            <span>0</span>
            <button>+</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

React component should return single element.
In the current situation **div**